# Django template language - multiple variables in the same line?

Tags: django

This seems like such a basic concept, but as a Django beginner i couldn't find an answer to it anywhere.

What is the meaning of:

```
{% varname1 varname2 varname3 varname4 %}
```

Would that line just "print" to the page the value of each of those variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see `{%`/`%}` in a template, that's a template tag, and it operates similar to a function. The first component (`varname1` above), is the name of the tag, and the remaining components are the arguments. If the template tag returns a result it's injected into the template. Plenty more information here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags